# Iterate through all the properties of an object skipping first one

Tags: javascript

Is there any method to skip iterating first element like gt(0) in jQuery
This is the code I am using

```
 for(var prop in item){
   alert(prop + " = " + item[prop]);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't rely on the order of the properties of the JavaScript objects because the properties are unordered. JQuery's gt works on an array and if you want to achieve something similar, you need the re-design your JSON model, something like:

```
 var item = [
{
   prop: "value"
},
{
   prop1: "value2"
}];
```

After wrapping your object properties in an array you can use it like this:

```
var i = item.length - (item.length - 1);

for (i; i < item.length; i++) {
    for (var k in item[i]) {
        alert(k + "=" + item[i][k]);
    }

}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bQzZd/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Object.hasOwnProperty`:

```
var item = {foo: 'bar', bar: 'baz'};

if (item.hasOwnProperty('foo')) {
    console.log(item['foo']);
}
```

You could also test for keys using `Object.keys`:

```
if (Object.keys(item).indexOf('foo') !== -1) {
    console.log(item['foo']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (prop !== item[0]){
  if (item.hasOwnProperty(prop){
    alert(prop + " = " + item[prop]);
  }
}
```

Placing that inside your `for in` loop should take care of that for you.  Please note that you will want to use `object.hasOwnProperty` to make sure you are not iterating over functions or other objects inherited from the prototype chain.

Note that when using `for in` loops in JavaScript:

> The ECMA standard does not specify an enumeration order but the de facto standard for non-array objects is to enumerate properties according to the order of their original assignment.

via http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/exploring-javascript-for-in-loops/

Comment: Are you assuming that item is an array? item[0] will return undefined otherwise (unless the property is called 0)

Comment: I suppose I am!  Thanks for the catch, Pencho.  I suppose you could always add a counter variable before the for in loop.

Answer (score 0):

straight solution: you can use continue in js loops to skip an iteration/element. if (index == 0) continue.

but definitely consider what people have said above.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function which is able to iterate by indexes of properties definded in parameters of function. Two first arguments are such as parameters in slice/substr.
These parameters aren't mandatory. We'll had able to calling by:

```
 someObject.customIterate( callback );
```

That means ->from = 0, to = -1   iterate through whole properties

```
 someObject.customIterate( from, callback)
```

That means iterate from value of `from`  property to the end.

```
Object.prototype.customIterate = function( from, to, callback ) {

   var f, t;
   if( ( f = typeof from === "function" ) ||  ( t = typeof to === "function" ) ) {
        callback = f ? from : to;
        to = -1;
        from = f ? 0 : from;

    }else if( !callback ) {
        return ;
    }

   for( var i in this) {
        if( from-- > 0 ) {
           continue;
        } else if( to-- ) {
            callback.call( this, i, this[i] );
        } else break;
    }
};
```

Callback gets two arguments - name of property and its value.
Callback is invoked in the context of `this` which is object from  which customIterate was called on.

And now:

```
var item = { a: 0, b: 1, c: 2, d: 4 };

item.customIterate( 1, function( prop, value ) {
   // if( this.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) ;// if you need that
        alert( prop + "=" + value );


});
```

Demo on: http://jsfiddle.net/hLhR9/