# Loop through columns in oracle apex

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, iteration, oracle-apex

In oracle apex columns of a tabular form can be controlled with their respective flow ID.  An example of a flow ID would be --> f01 <--(column 1) or --> f02 <-- (column 2), basically fXX where XX is the column number.  I am trying to loop through the columns given their respective column number.

What I am trying to do is concatenate the value of x (column number) to

`document.wwv_flow.f+x.toString()+[i]`

I am feeling pretty confident is not the correct method of handing the situation but I do not know what is the correct method.

Note: $v(APEX_ITEM) returns the value of the apex item.

Full Code:

```
     for (var i = 0; i < document.wwv_flow.f01.length; i++) //document.wwv_flow.f01.length returns the number rows
 {
     var isChecked=$(document.wwv_flow.f01[i]).is(":checked");

     if(isChecked){
         var copyrow;
         apex.widget.tabular.addRow();
         copyrow = apex.jQuery(apex.widget.tabular.gTabForm).find("tr").last().insertBefore(apex.jQuery(apex.widget.tabular.gTabForm).find("tr").first());
         i++;
         copyrow.hide();
         var colcount = $(document.wwv_flow.f01[i]).closest("tr").children("td").length; //colcount is the number of columns
         for(var x = 4; x < (colcount-4); x++){    //x is the column number    
             if(x < 10){ 
                 x = "0"+x;
             }
             console.log("Col #"+x+" Value: "+$v((document.wwv_flow.f+x.toString()+[i]))); //!!
         }
         copyrow.show( "slow" );

     }
 }
```

Comment: Currently am  thinking that this might be somehow related to the situation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677034/iterate-through-all-the-properties-of-an-object-skipping-first-one

Comment: What's the reason for this code where you concat the whole array? There are better ways to reliably access the columns in a tab form through JS due to apex's markup for them, too.

Comment: Actually I found an solution directly before I left. Will post solution when tomorrow morning. ~Sent from phone

Comment: Can you elaborate on the purpose of this code? Ultimately what are you looking to achieve?

Comment: Certainly!  It will go thru and grab the values of each row for which you can do whatever you want with it.  In my example I have it simply printing out to console.

Comment: I'm still unclear as to how you intend on using this in the real world, but if you're satisfied I'll leave it at that. I just question why you even need JavaScript to do this.. I'm guessing that there may be a better pl/sql solution.

Comment: I agree with @hisnameismyname2 and it's the exact reason as to why I was asking for your ulterior motive. I can make sure your code breaks with some basic actions, for example. Tabular forms and index-based array-getting can shut down your logic if you're not aware of how things work. And as said, there is likely PLSQL logic available to do what you want. Furthermore, take into account the new Interactive Grid component in Apex 5.1.

Comment: This is currently being used as a multi faucet tool.  The first thing that it is used for is to duplicate rows (as seen in `var copyrow`), the second feature is to compare certain columns with various page items and the third use is for copying the entire page (I would need many more characters to explain the process).  To answer your inquires yes there are PL/SQL options but they are very clunky and are actually was I was currently using before this logic.  Finally yes, I am not sure what 5.1 will bring, which is why I more or less rag-tagged this answer together.  Thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that will loop through and print each column value for rows where the checkbox has been checked.  There could be a better solution yet but for now this is what I have come up with:

I am pretty sure Oracle apex only allows 50 columns in tabular forms and this code will loop through the values of input columns.  If the column is read only then you need to use

`$(obj[key][i]).text();` instead of `$v(obj[key][i])`

I setup a button to run a JavaScript dynamic action and used the following code

```
var tabForm = { //these are tabular form columns
    1:document.wwv_flow.f01 ,
    2:document.wwv_flow.f02 ,
    3:document.wwv_flow.f03 ,
    4:document.wwv_flow.f04 ,
    5:document.wwv_flow.f05 ,
    6:document.wwv_flow.f06 ,
    7:document.wwv_flow.f07 ,
    8:document.wwv_flow.f08 ,
    9:document.wwv_flow.f09 ,
    10:document.wwv_flow.f10 ,
    11:document.wwv_flow.f11 ,
    12:document.wwv_flow.f12 ,
    13:document.wwv_flow.f13 ,
    14:document.wwv_flow.f14 ,
    15:document.wwv_flow.f15 ,
    16:document.wwv_flow.f16 ,
    17:document.wwv_flow.f17 ,
    18:document.wwv_flow.f18 ,
    19:document.wwv_flow.f19 ,
    20:document.wwv_flow.f20 ,
    21:document.wwv_flow.f21 ,
    22:document.wwv_flow.f22 ,
    23:document.wwv_flow.f23 ,
    24:document.wwv_flow.f24 ,
    25:document.wwv_flow.f25 ,
    26:document.wwv_flow.f26 ,
    27:document.wwv_flow.f27 ,
    28:document.wwv_flow.f28 ,
    29:document.wwv_flow.f29 ,
    30:document.wwv_flow.f30 ,
    31:document.wwv_flow.f31 ,
    32:document.wwv_flow.f32
    //Up to 50 Columns
}

for (var i = 0; i < document.wwv_flow.f01.length; i++)
 {
     var isChecked=$(document.wwv_flow.f01[i]).is(":checked");      
     if(isChecked){
         var colcount = $(document.wwv_flow.f01[i]).closest("tr").children("td").length;
         var obj = tabForm;
         for(var x = 4; x < (colcount-3); x++){           
             Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
                 if(key != x) return;
                 console.log(key, $v(obj[key][i]));
             });
         }             
     }
 }
```